# If I see someone using the same inferior answer, is downvoting right?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

Something I've seen frequently (mainly from one but a couple others as well) is an answer that could be improved with a more efficient answer. I have reached out to these users (one many times) but it has fallen on deaf ears. They always use the same approach even though a different one would be much better, especially with much larger sets of data (I post almost exclusively in the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag).

At this point, it honestly frustrates me that someone who does have a lot of reputation and *should* know about the difference in the performance of the strategies, doesn't want to improve their answers; it feels like the old phrase "you can't teach an old dog new tricks."

I'm intentionally leaving the actual scenario out, but for those of you that use C# it's like using `Parameters.AddWithValue` instead of `Parameters.Add` when querying a `varchar`. Yes, it works, yes it *is* useful to the person who asked the question, but it's not good. C# will pass that value as an `nvarchar` causing any indexes not to be used. The answer they give is useful, it *will* solve the question, but why use it when a better option is available?

In the past, I have also posted answers that use the "better" solution as well, but honestly, I think it would be just *better* if the other person used  what has been proved to be more performant.

I realise that anyone can use their downvotes for anything, but I kind of disagree with the downvote reason, which is defined as "the answer is not useful." It *is* useful, but just could be better, and it disappoints me that the users continue to use a solution that could be improved on.

This isn't to say I won't stop answering on those questions, I still will when I have the time, but just wonder if downvoting is actually the right choice from a community point of view.

Comment: Voting is quality control. Apply it as much as possible to ensure it has the helps the many many people who will view the answers and worry less about the one person who has provided that answe.

Comment: People copy code from Stack Overflow all the time. If someone posts an answer which uses bad practices, that's a problem. Feel free to vote (but also comment to the effect of what the problem is, so others reading the answer can see it, and so OP *might* fix it)

Comment: @Lamu i am quite unsure, i thought using Parameters.AddWithValue was the standard, But i hate people which downvote a legitimate answer. You can add you better answer and comment on the not so go answer, but downvoting a valid answer is wrong

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) @nbk .

Comment: @CertainPerformance deaf ears don't hear though. I can't making the same comment when they don't read them; it's simply a waste of my time.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but the comment is *also* for readers who would otherwise blindly copy code from the answer.

Comment: @Lamu but [MS tells in this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.8) that that it replaces Add and so i also didn't mind using it

Comment: @nbk from that link you give: *"AddWithValue replaces the SqlParameterCollection.Add method that takes a **String and an Object.**"* Emphasis mine. Not the overload method that uses String, and a SQLDbType, with possible more parameters for scale, precision, etc (which are the ones you *should* be using). *We are far off topic here now though.*

Comment: @Lamu you are right, i was irritated as in the commenst where mentioned to downvote such answers, but they aren't wrong and so a downvote is **wrong**

Comment: @nbk A downvote is _not_ wrong. When I see two answers to a question and one uses an inferior technique or library I do downvote because it is quality control, even though the answer technically works. I also downvote SQL that is open to injection attacks even if it technically answers the question. Bad practise can be dangerous and there are too many users just copy/pasting code without knowing better.

Answer (score 8):

One word:

### Downvotes

If you see someone posting an inferior or low quality answer, you can use downvotes to show your disapproval even if the solution offered is technically correct and works.

Downvotes are your [Shepherd's crook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepherd%27s_crook). You don't lash your sheep with it; you use it to guide them and teach them the way. If a predator comes around, don't be afraid to use it to defend.

If you want to teach others that answers using an inferior practice are not recommended simply downvote every time you come across such answer.

I do something similar in mysqli tag. If an answer suggests use of `mysqli_error()` or doesn't use prepared statements I downvote even if the answer solves the problem OP asked about. If one wants to write an answer, it has to be a very good answer otherwise it is just noise that propagates sloppy code.

Of course, if possible and if it is the right thing to do, suggest a better answer. If someone else provides a better answer, upvote it.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that there's hardly a reason to downvote if the answer works, even if not as efficient as it could be.

But if you know a better way, and you also know that answer poster won't take your improvement comments into consideration, *just write a concurrent answer* where you explain the advantages of your solution compared to a slower/less efficient solution that you can mention, without linking to the other answer.

> when querying a varchar, it's better to use `Parameters.Add` instead of  `Parameters.AddWithValue` because ...

In that case, you offer a better solution, and statistically your answer will get more upvotes in the long run. Check some popular questions, they have 40+ answers, sometimes very similar and lots of votes (sometimes someone has to clean that mess, oh my), so you're not going to pollute the thread with one concurrent answer.

Now, from what you describe, it seems that those users answer a lot of duplicate questions. In that case, flag as duplicate instead of answering, of course. And sometimes a stray downvote may hit an answer on a classic question asked 100 times. I'm not going to blame the downvoter...